# How to change keyboard layout on xmonad + Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xmonad

I want to configure the system without using setxkbmap. What configuration files are responsible for setting xkb? I tried to change the contents of the file: /etc/keyboard, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ubuntu setxkbmap man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/setxkbmap.1.html), it's written:

```
   An XKB keymap is constructed from a  number  of  components  which  are
   compiled  only  as needed.  The source for all of the components can be
   found in /usr/share/X11/xkb.
```